# What easing functions are allowed in jquery-scrollify?

Tags: jquery-scrollify, easing-functions

What are all the possible options for the "easing" attribute in the scrollify function? I have tried several, but they all break the scrolling functionality except the default "easeOutExpo"

Comment: Please include some code samples of your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the easing properties requires an easing library. The owner of the package recommends [this one](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/). I refer to that based on other closed easing questions on their public issue tracker such as:
https://github.com/lukehaas/Scrollify/issues/42

I would also in the future recommend checking out a package's github open issues, or related forums for specific questions. For example [Scrollify's is here.](https://github.com/lukehaas/Scrollify/issues)